# How to make ranking system in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php application which has workout table where I am storing daily users workout data based on activity(like: run, walk, cycling). At the end of the month I have to create a leaderboard to generate rank based on highest workout points.

```
SELECT total_distance, user_id,date_created 
   FROM workouts 
   WHERE date_created LIKE '%2019-11%' AND activity_type='Run'.
```

with the above query I am getting output as mention below

[image: table output after executing first query]

I have optimized the query by using GROUP BY user_id in query.

```
SELECT SUM(total_distance) as points, user_id,date_created 
    FROM workouts 
    WHERE date_created LIKE '%2019-11%' AND activity_type='Run' 
    GROUP BY user_id
```

[image: table output after executing 2nd query]

I want my final output as shown in 2nd image along with rank as new column.
How to write a query for that. I am not able to do it..

Comment: Presumably, `LIKE '2019-11%'` would work just as well, and has the advantage that it can use an index (although a range query would be faster still)

Answer (score 0):

I would change this condition

```
date_created LIKE '%2019-11%'
```

into

```
month(date_created) = '11' and year(date_created) = '2019'
```

Final query, order rows by  points desc and use `row_numbers()` or `danse_rank()` for creating ranking.

Function `row_numbers()`and `danse_rank()` are introduced since `MySQL version >= 8` and since `MariaDB >= 10.2.0.`

For newer versions (`MySQL version >= 8` OR `MariaDB >= 10.2.0.`)

```
    SELECT SUM(total_distance) as points, user_id, date_created, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points desc) as rank

    FROM workouts 

    WHERE month(date_created) = '11' AND year(date_created) = '2019' AND activity_type='Run' 
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY points desc
```

For older versions (`MySQL version < 8` OR `MariaDB < 10.2.0.`)

This is also working for (`MySQL version >= 8` OR `MariaDB >= 10.2.0.`)

```
    SET @rank=0;
    SELECT SUM(total_distance) as points, user_id, date_created, 
    @rank:=@rank+1 as rank

    FROM workouts 

    WHERE month(date_created) = '11' AND year(date_created) = '2019' AND activity_type='Run' 
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY points desc
```

Comment: @DineshVishwakarma can you copy that error here? and tell me which version od mysql do you use?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; checkk the version manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to user near '(ORDER BY points desc) AS rank FROM workouts WHERE month(date_created)='11'.

Comment: @DineshVishwakarma probably the problem is in mysql version, I will update my answer

Comment: This is simply a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry can you tell my way?

Comment: Because a function cannot use an index.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT 
   CASE WHEN @l=points THEN @rank ELSE @rank:=@rank+1 END as rank,@l:=points ,points,user_id from (select 
   SUM(total_distance) as points, user_id,date_created 
    FROM workouts 
    WHERE date_created LIKE '%2019-07%'  
    GROUP BY user_id order by points desc) a, (SELECT@rank := 0) vars;
```

SQL Demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e8634/2

Comment: I am getting the correct output with your query, but what if I have two or three users with same points....it should give me rank as 1, 2,2,2,3 so on....@sel

Comment: In this case, need to compare the points. i make the amendments.

Comment: I add in a IF statement  to increase the rank when points not same. Otherwise use back the same rank.

Comment: I have total points as 150, 150, 30,20, and rank is 1,2,3,4. but I want rank as 1,1,2,3